# H2O Deviance - Negative Binomial

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, deviance, h2o

I'm hoping to get some clarifications on the deviance calculation of negative binomial.
From H2O [documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#negative-binomial), the deviance formula for negative binomial regression is expressed as:

$$D=2\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bigg\{y_{i}\log\bigg(\frac{y_{i}}{\mu_{i}}\bigg)-\big(y_{i}+\theta^{-1}\big)\log\bigg(\frac{1+\theta y_{i}}{1+\theta \mu_{i}}\bigg)\bigg\}$$

I'm trying to get confirmation on what the deviance should be when the response ($y_i$) OR the predict ($\mu_i$) being 0.
I saw in the H2O [code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-algos/src/main/java/hex/glm/GLMModel.java) (line 579 & 958) that when either of them are 0, the deviance is set to 0. I can see that when both are 0, the deviance is 0, but struggling to see how it is 0 when only one of the two is 0?

Could anyone please explain to me how the deviance is calculated to be 0 when only one of the response OR predict is 0?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic on Cross Validated but you may have a question about the Negative Binomial deviance. Please revise your question to introduce the notation you use, in text rather than code. Hint about #1: The two terms have different sign in the equation but the same sign in the code. What do you know about log(a/b) and log(b/a)?

Comment: Thanks dipetkov for your comment. For #1 yes of course, I should've picked that up. I will re-post my question for #2 with your advised format.